# Converting String into 8 bit Binary

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert a string into an 8 bit binary number. So far, my code can convert each character value into binary but not into 8 bits and not in the correct order.

My code is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char startingString[40] = "Man";
   int i;
   int j = 0;
   int k;
   int p;
   int decimalString[3000];
   int binaryString[3000];
   int quotient;
   int decimal;
   int testString[3000];

   // Convert the ASCII characters into their decimal equivalents. 
  for(i=0; i<3; i++){
      decimalString[i] = startingString [i];
      //testString[i] = startingString [i];
     // printf("%d\n", decimalString[i]);
  }


     for(k=0; k<3; k++){
     quotient = decimalString[k];
     decimal = decimalString[k];
     while (decimal != 0){
         quotient = decimal%2;
         binaryString[j] = quotient;
         decimal = decimal/2;
         j++;

     }



    for(p=j-1; p>=0; p--){
      printf("%d", binaryString[p]);

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Im wondering what I can do to fix the order of the code and turn it into 8 bits for each ASCII character. 
Thank you!

Comment: You have to use a counter that's set to 8 instead of `!= 0`.

Comment: Your output is in mirrored order?

Comment: Use something like that: `char src[] = "Hello dude";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(src); i++){printf("%d ", src[i]);}`.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you like to print the binary values MSB-first. You did not show us the expected output…

Since it sounds like homework or similar learning task, I will not post a complete source. This code snippet might help you:

```
k = 0;
for (j = 1 << 7; j != 0; j >>= 1) {
    binaryString[k] = (startingString[i] & j) != 0;
    k++;
}
```

- The expression `1 << 7` evaluates to a value that has only the MSB of a 8-bit character set.
- The instruction `j >>= 1` shifts down this bit by 1 bit.
- If the value in `j` is 1 (the LSB set) and shifted right, the result is zero. That's why the loops runs as long as `j` is not yet zero.
- The binary AND operator `&` "masks" the bit in the character, which is set in `j`. Comparing the result with zero evaluates to 1 or 0, for `true` and `false`, resp.

*Note: To follow the logic and the values, insert some `printf()` at interesting places and print interesting values.*